# Simulating a random process with AWGN

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, noise

I am trying to simulate the following random process:

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = f(y) + AN(t) $$

where $N(t)$ is additive Gaussian white noise, which, if I remember right, is defined by $\int\limits_0^t N(t) dt$ having zero mean and a variance of $t$.

Aside from the noise, I know I can simulate $\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y)$ as

$$y[k+1] = y[k] + f(y[k])\Delta t$$

as long as the dynamics of the system are much slower than $\Delta t$, for example, if $f(y) = y/\tau$ then the requirement is $\Delta t \ll \tau$.

**How does the simulation get changed when adding noise?**

I think it scales so that if you halve the timestep, then you have to use random Gaussian samples with variance that halves, e.g. standard deviation divides by $\sqrt{2}$, so I think this would work:

$$y[k+1] = y[k] + f(y[k])\Delta t + An[k]\sqrt{\Delta t}$$

where $n[k]$ is a series of independent samples of a Gaussian distribution with zero mean and $\sigma = 1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: See Euler-Maruyama method to integrate a SDE. You might want to refine your understanding of the difference between white noise and Wiener process/Brownian motion.

Comment: I do understand the difference between white noise and a Wiener process which is the integral of white noise, I'm just trying to remember how to apply it to simulating a differential equation.

Comment: from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method : `def dW(delta_t): 
    """Sample a random number at each call."""
    return np.random.normal(loc = 0.0, scale = np.sqrt(delta_t))` -- so it looks like I was right about $\sqrt{\Delta t}$

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to give a name to your method. "Additive white noise" seems like a handwaving construction using a non-function in $N$. The SDE formalism, Ito or Stratanovich, was developed to avoid using functions that take the value infinity almost everywhere.